# Using django-extensions' CreationDateTimeField with South

Tags: django, django-models, django-extensions

I've upgraded a number of

```
created = django.db.models.DateTimeField
```

to

```
created = django_extensions.db.fields.CreationDateTimeField
```

however, when I run

```
./manage.py schemamigration app --auto
```

then

```
./manage.py migrate app
```

I get

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-05-13 11:09:45.149280) while time zone support is active.
```

Is there anything special I need to do to tell south about that django-extensions field?

This is the actual migration code:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    # Changing field 'Advertiser.updated'
    db.alter_column('advertiser', 'updated', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')())
    # Changing field 'Advertiser.created'
    db.alter_column('advertiser', 'created', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')())
    # Adding field 'Campaign.created'
    db.add_column('advertiser_campaign', 'created',
                  self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True),
                  keep_default=False)

    # Adding field 'Campaign.updated'
    db.add_column('advertiser_campaign', 'updated',
                  self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(default=datetime.datetime.now, blank=True),
                  keep_default=False)
```

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Did you recently change USE_TZ=True in settings.py? Your issue might not be South related, look [over this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#migration-guide) and see if it is relevant.

Comment: USE_TZ was always true and is the reason we upgraded to CreationDateTime.  We had DateTime(auto_add_now=True), but it was causing all manners of problems with data migrations and data imports